# Calling presentViewController from viewDidAppear causes ViewController to be leaked

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have three UIViewController derived class instances A, B, C

A: is a view with a single button which is linked to buttonPressed and the following nonstandard code

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed {
    B = new local object of class B code left out for brevity
    B.dismissDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:B
                       animated:NO
                     completion:nil];
}
- (void)dismiss {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

B: is a view that has the following nonstandard code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    C = new local object of class C code left out for brevity
    C.dismissDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:C
                       animated:NO
                     completion:nil];       
}
- (void)dismiss {
    [self.dismissDelegate dismiss];
}
```

C: is a view that has one button linked to buttonPressed

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed {
    [self.dismissDelegate dismiss];
}
```

Pressing the button on A then the button on C repeatedly causes multiple copies of C to be allocated which are never released. However if B is removed and A just launches C the copies of C are released.

ARC is turned on.

Comment: How is your delegate property declared?  Is it `weak` or `strong` ?

Comment: Delegate was declared strong but behaviour remains when declared weak

Comment: I just created a simple app that reproduces what you have shown here and it doesn't leak.  I added an NSLog to ViewController B's dealloc and as soon as VC C is dismissed, VC B is dealloc'd so your problem must be related to something you haven't shown here.  You may have a bigger issue though because the app crashes under iOS 8 with an attempt to dismiss a model VC that isn't presented.

Comment: A strong delegate property in VC C did cause a leak however